# C# Deserialize XML elements with attributes into List

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing, xml-deserialization

Here's the XML:

```
<xml id = "1234">
    <connect id="2"/>
    <connect id="1"/>
    <connect id="21"/>
    <connect id="3"/>
    <connect id="7"/>
</xml>
```

Currently I am doing this:

```
public class xml
{
    //Constructor

    [XmlAttribute ("id")]
    public uint id;

    [XmlElement ("connect")]
    public List<Connection> Connections { get; set; }

    //Deserializer
}

public class Connection
{
    [XmlAttribute ("id")]
    public uint id { get; set; }
}
```

The goal is to get rid of the Connection class entirely and Deserialize the xml straight into:

```
List<uint> connections;
```

Answer (score 1):

<s>First, your XML is not valid, i guess it's just a typo - there no end tag for `"connect"`.</s>

I recommend you to use linq [`XDocument`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument(v=vs.110).aspx).
Then it's easy:

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
List<uint> list = xdoc
                    .Descendants("connect")
                    .Select(node => uint.Parse(node.Attribute("id").Value))
                    .ToList();
```

Comment: Is there a way to achieve this using `System.Xml.Serialization`?

Comment: Thanks!  This was exactly the solution I was looking for. I didn't realize the potential of XDocument.

Comment: `<connect />` is self closing. why shouldn't it be valid then?

Comment: @da_berni, the question was edited and fixed after i've posted that